# Return value from multiple columns if the column is the most recent previous year

Tags: r, categorical-data

I'd just like to have a table that contains the ID and a new categorical variable (called e.g. Actual_landcover, having 40 categories) which is derived from the variables LandcoverXXXX and Sub_landcoverXXXX.

I have a dataset that contains variables

```
ID,
Year (2014-2023),
Landcover2013 (categorical variable 1-4),
Landcover2015,
Landcover2017,
Landcover2019,
Landcover2021,
Sub_landcover2013 (subcategories 1-10),
Sub_landcover2015,
Sub_landcover2017,
Sub_landcover2019,
Sub_landcover2021
```

I'd like to add a new column in my dataset. The new column would contain a new categorical variable describing the actual landcover (4 x 10 = 40, because of all those categories and subcategories the values can range from 1 to 40, in theory). And because there is temporal variation in the landcover values, I want the clause to utilize the newest data available based on the variable '*Year*'. For example, if the '*Year*' is 2014 the data used for a new value is from variables '*Landcover2013*' and '*Sub_landcover2013*'. And for example, with the '*Year*' 2015 I want to use the same data from 2013 because the landcover data is published at the end of those years mentioned in the existing column names.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
             Year = c("2014", "2014", "2016", "2017", "2023"),
             Landcover2013 = c("1", "1", "2", "1", "4"),
             Landcover2015 = c("1", "1", "3", "2", "4"),
             Landcover2017 = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3"),
             Landcover2019 = c("2", "1", "2", "2", "4"),
             Landcover2021 = c("2", "1", "3", "1", "4"),
             Sub_landcover2013 = c("4", "7", "5", "9", "1"),
             Sub_landcover2015 = c("5", "7", "6", "9", "2"),
             Sub_landcover2017 = c("4", "6", "6", "9", "1"),
             Sub_landcover2019 = c("4", "6", "6", "9", "2"),
             Sub_landcover2021 = c("4", "6", "6", "10", "1"))
```

The following two tables are just examples of rules which could derive new values. The new values could be formed like:

```
    LandcoverXXXX Sub_landcoverXXXX New_value
1              1                 1         1
2              1                 2         2
3              1                 3         3
4              1                 4         4
5              1                 5         5
6              1                 6         6
7              1                 7         7
8              1                 8         8
9              1                 9         9
10             1                10        10
11             2                 1        11
12             2                 2        12
13             2                 3        13
14             2                 4        14
15             2                 5        15
16             2                 6        16
17             2                 7        17
18             2                 8        18
19             2                 9        19
20             2                10        20
21             3                 1        21
```

and so on...

OR like:

```
   LandcoverXXXX Sub_landcoverXXXX New_value
1              1                 1        11
2              1                 2        12
3              1                 3        13
4              1                 4        14
5              1                 5        15
6              1                 6        16
7              1                 7        17
8              1                 8        18
9              1                 9        19
10             1                10       110
11             2                 1        21
12             2                 2        22
13             2                 3        23
14             2                 4        24
15             2                 5        25
16             2                 6        26
17             2                 7        27
18             2                 8        28
19             2                 9        29
20             2                10       210
21             3                 1        31
```

and so on...

But those two tables are just examples of how the new values could be formed. The final output table could look like this:

```
  ID Actual_landcover
1  1               14
2  2               17
3  3               36
4  4               29
5  5               41
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some sample data and its desired output? For instance, you could create a toy dataset with 2-3 landcover and sublandcovers columns and 4-5 rows of data. But putting [data as images is highly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12109788)

Comment: I don't understand how your sample input (`df`) has 5 rows of data but your sample output (`recoding_table`) has 12 rows. And the output seems to have all values of 1 for landcover but there appear to be only 8 1's in the input to start with. How do these values match up? I assumed you were only trying to get the green values from the image but that doesn't seem to be the case. It's still not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should put in a target result. I found your description confusing. Perhaps the existing answer is correct, but if so you should give it a checkmark so people will know what was desired.

Comment: Your new example outputs have confused the issue further. For instance, there are no landcover year values so it's impossible to see where each value has come from. Also, you only have 5 values per landcover type per row. If you are wanting separate landcover columns, based on your sample data it will result in only five rows per id. How are you expecting 10 rows per id to be derived? Please update your question with some example data that better reflects your desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This answer was posted prior to the OP's update and is for replicating the pattern highlighted in the data image only.

Using `tidyverse` packages, here's a way to achieve your goal. The workflow:

1. Get all your landcover types columns into a single column using `pivot_longer()`
2. Create two new group columns, for for landcover type and one for landcover type years
3. Group data by id and landcover type (e.g. "group" column)
4. `slice()` each group by the maximum year in "group1" column that is less than the value in the "Year" column
5. `pivot_wider()` to get two separate landcover type columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

result <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, Year, NEW_COLUMN)) %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(str_detect(name, "^Land") ~ "landcover",
                           TRUE ~ "sub_landcover"),
         group1 = as.integer(str_sub(name, start = -4))) %>%
  group_by(id, group) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(as.integer(Year) - group1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, Year),
              names_from = group,
              values_from = value)

result
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  id    Year  landcover sub_landcover
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>        
1 1     2014  1         4            
2 2     2014  1         7            
3 3     2016  3         6            
4 4     2017  2         9            
5 5     2023  4         1
```